# Pass page title variable to layout apps view Laravel components

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to set a page title variable in my controllers' methods and pass it to layouts/app.blade.php since every page has a title and DRY. I'm using Laravel 8 and slots/components. Except this doesn't work.  How do I do this?

TaskController.php

```
public function create()
{
    return view('tasks.create')->withTitle('Create Task');
}
```

layouts/apps.blade.php

```
<main class="flex-grow">
    <h1>{{ $title }}</h1>
    {{ $slot }}
</main>
```

Comment: Normally slots are used with components. You would call the component from the blade (layout) file.. But that shouldnt prevent title from being displayed.

Comment: What if you tried this: `view('tasks.create' )->with('title', 'Create Task');` OR  `view('tasks.create', ['title' => 'Create task' ]);`

Comment: @TimLewis yeah a typo